# iPhone only vibrates when debugging app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

I'm programming an iPhone app that requires repeated vibration until the user stops it, and I am doing it with a loop called by a thread like so:

```
-(void)vibrateLoop {
    while (1) {
        sleep(0.5);
        if (!vibrate) {
            [NSThread exit];
            return;
        }
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the app from my iPhone rather than from Xcode, the vibration refuses to happen. But when running it in Xcode in debug mode, the phone vibrates just like it is supposed to. What is going on?

Comment: Try instead putting the Play call in a method, and calling that method with a timer that is set to repeat.

Comment: You have vibration enabled in Settings, right?

Comment: Hooray, Ill put it as a question then, so other people can see it. I think the problem is to do with using sleep, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead putting the Play call in a method, and calling that method with a timer that is set to repeat. EG

```
  -(void)vibrateLoop {

    if (!vibrate) {

        return;
    }
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(vibrateLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

}

//somewhere else in code
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(vibrateLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the graphic services framework library. It has a method

> void GSEventVibrateForDuration(float secs);

You can set secs to 1 and keep calling this method in a loop and when the user wants it to stop use the following method GSEventStopvibrator()

Important:The graphic services framework library is a private library,so if you decide to use it you wont be able to submit your app to the app store.